# Retrieving the JSON data into a list view

Tags: android, json, httpclient

I successfully opened `Httpclient` connection. Now I want to select data from JSON and show it in a list. I googled it from half day but can't find any help. A sample project or code snippet would be really helpful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse JSON into a ListView friendly output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982700/parse-json-into-a-listview-friendly-output)

Comment: I understand wanting help, but claiming that you've already searched seems a little far-fetched in this case.

Answer (score 2):

In the past I've used [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to parse JSON. The `org.json` package provided in the SDK seems a little low-level.

> Now I want to select data from JSON
>   and show it in a list.

When you say "select data" do you mean use queries to retrieve subsets of your data? [jxpath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) looks like an interesting solution. If you're just displaying the entire JSON data then you should be able to simply wrap gson's output in an adapter.

> I googled it
>   from half day but can't find any help.

- [DuckDuckGo: json android](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=json%20android)
- [DuckDuckGo: json android listview](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=json%20android%20listview)
- [Stack Overflow: json android listview](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=json%20android%20listview)

The last one would have led you to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1982700/parse-json-into-a-listview-friendly-output), of which yours is an exact duplicate.

> A sample project or code snippet would
>   be really helpful.

Examples abound! From the above search links:

- [gson parsing](http://benjii.me/2010/04/deserializing-json-in-android-using-gson/)
- [gson parsing and displaying in a ListView](https://bobbyprabowo.wordpress.com/2010/11/25/android-json-processing-using-gson-and-display-in-on-a-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONTokener.html or something similar to decode your JSON data.

After doing that you need to update your list model on your list view.

I'm under the impression that for your application http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html might suit your needs.

If you already have an array adapter, you probably just need to update that adapter.

I don't have specifics on that though.  Hopefully this will put you on the right track.